# React native flow error: Computed properties may only be primitive literal values

Tags: react-native, flowtype

I am having flow types error

Here is my error:

Cannot use `field` [1] as a computed property. Computed properties may only be primitive literal values, but this one may be either string literal `amountFrom`

Here is my code:

```
    const handleChangeAmountInputs = (value, field) => {
        if (value.includes(',')) {
          setAmountFilter({
            ...amountFilter,
            [field]: value.split(',').join(''),
          });
        } else {
          setAmountFilter({...amountFilter, [field]: value});
        }
      };

and here is how i call the function

      <TextInput
        placeholder={'Enter amount'}
        returnKeyType="done"
        keyboardType="decimal-pad"
        onChangeText={(value) => {
        handleChangeAmountInputs(value, 'amountFrom');
        }}
       />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming based solely on the code snippet you've provided, flow must be implicitly typing your `field` arg as a string literal as opposed to a string.

If you add a type annotation to field, I think it should fix it.

```
const handleChangeAmountInputs = (value, field: string) => {
```